# Cannot boot on any device if hard disk inserted

Tags: boot, bios, mbr

Suddenly, I cannot boot from any device (hard disk, CD, USB): I get just a black screen and nothing else. When digging in this issue, I tried removing the hard drive and now I'm able to boot from CD and USB.

If I "connect" the hard drive to a virtual machine, it works fine.

As far as I understand, my BIOS (Phoenix) is reading the hard drive, if present, and is finding something that it's not liking. I suppose that if I remove all the partitions it will boot, however I'm not sure and I would like to avoid that option.

So I'm here to ask: what is the BIOS doing with the hard disk and why doesn't it allow to boot from any device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the BIOS to the latest version resolved the problem.

Here is how I did it. First of all, I knew that the hard disk, its boot sector, its partition table and all the filesystem were OK because they were working in a virtual machine. So I tried to find a way to boot into the operating system using the computer:

- I changed the boot sequence in order to have USB first and hard disk last;
- I removed the hard disk;
- I inserted a USB key with Ubuntu and booted into it;
- I re-inserted the hard disk (via SATA, that supports hotplug);
- I asked Ubuntu to boot into the hard disk.

This way, I could access the operating system on the hard disk, download the BIOS upgrade tools from the manufacturer website and proceed with the upgrade.

Comment: Actually, it's best if the answer would possibly mention a trail of how you found the solution, to help other users. It should be marked as the answer if it's the answer the ultimately helped you.

Comment: @CanadianLuke: done. If you need me to further improve the question or the answer, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I suggest you to reset the bios using the jumpers. When you have done this the comeback hd boot in its original door (1SATA, 2sata, 3sata ....) 
As soon as the PC starts to enter the bios and go to the BOOT menu item and configures the device order.

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 factors here :

1. BIOS Boot order looks for this hard drive first
2. Hard drive has a bad boot sector

Therefore, 2 solutions :

1. In the BIOS Setup, you should have a Boot menu where you can organize boot device. Delete this hard drive or put it at the end.
2. Erase the boot sector : first back it up then erase it. On a GNU/Linux system you can issue these commands :

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/mbr-backup bs=512 count=1 # Back up the whole MBR`

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1 # erase the boot sector`

But for your information, deleting all the partitions will not solve your problem. The main boot sector isn't located on any partition, but on the first 446 bytes of the hard drive. Partitions are located after the 512th bytes, and described between the 446 and the 512th bytes. Modifying partition table doesn't affect the boot sector.